# Use foreground image as an alpha mask for the background image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to blend two images (one is a gif) together and have the background image only be shown where the foreground image is shown.

Example: If the foreground image is a "T" and the background image is a purple "X" I would expect to see [image]

I've tried using background blend mode, but that changed nothing.

Some code similar to mine, producing the results I am not trying to achieve:

```css
img {
  background-image: url("https://content.mycutegraphics.com/graphics/alphabet/purple-alphabet-letter-x.png");
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  
  background-size: 100px auto;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a0/Soccerball_mask_transparent_background.svg/760px-Soccerball_mask_transparent_background.svg.png" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use mask here:

```css
img {
  -webkit-mask-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/0DpJxc4/purple-alphabet-letter-x.png");
          mask-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/0DpJxc4/purple-alphabet-letter-x.png");
  
  -webkit-mask-size: 100% auto;
          mask-size: 100% auto;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a0/Soccerball_mask_transparent_background.svg/760px-Soccerball_mask_transparent_background.svg.png" />
```

And you can also keep the blending effect considering an extra container:

```css
img {
  -webkit-mask-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/0DpJxc4/purple-alphabet-letter-x.png");
          mask-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/0DpJxc4/purple-alphabet-letter-x.png");
  
  -webkit-mask-size: 100% auto;
          mask-size: 100% auto;
          
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  width: 100px;
  display:block;
}

.box {
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/0DpJxc4/purple-alphabet-letter-x.png");
  background-size:100% auto;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a0/Soccerball_mask_transparent_background.svg/760px-Soccerball_mask_transparent_background.svg.png" />
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, my question was unclear. I am trying to get an effect similar to your second code block, but instead of using the X as a mask, using the soccer ball as a mask.

Comment: @RaidenHi simply switch both images